# RemoteWebDriver IE Clicking Links doesn't work

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-rc, webdriver

I am using the RemoteWebDriver and trying to execute a couple of UI tests on a remote machine under Internet Explorer:

```
RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub"),  DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer());`
driver.get("http://bing.com");
driver.findElement(By.id("sb_form_q")).sendKeys("Cheese");
driver.findElement(By.id("sb_form_go")).click();
```

Using the following code works in FireFox and Chrome but not in IE.  IF I run a plain web driver on my local machine it works fine.  Does anyone know why this is the case or if there is a work around?

I am using Selenium-Server-Standalone-2.8.0 and the Selenium-Java-2.8.0 client drivers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had problems with clicking using RemoteWebDriver and IE capabilities. I solved it by using sendKeys(Keys.ENTER) for links/buttons and sendKeys(Keys.SPACE) for radio buttons/checkboxes.

Comment: Yea, it is actually and issue with the way the developers on that site coded it, their javascript is horrible and I just asked them to fix it, but I'll keep the send keys in mind. Also note that if IE is not zoomed to 100% you can also encounter problems.

Answer (score 0):

try with submit() instead of click() it should work.

Comment: That doesn't work for me, I can see on the server output that the submit and clicks both occur but the browser doesn't change it sits on the search page.  I cannot seem to get the clicking of links to occur.  As I mentioned before it does work in FF and Chrome.

Comment: This is not an issue with the code above, it was an issue with the ajax that was running on the website I was trying to test, click and submit both work.